# Is there a way to plot values from a google sheets workbook to tradingview pinescript?

Tags: google-sheets, pine-script

I am trying to plot values calculated in an GoogleSheets workbook on a tradingview chart. I cannot do the same calculations in Tradingview because the values come from a dynamic webpage, so I am doing the calculations in excel, and was wondering if its possible to send these values to Tradingview somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Pine currently does not have the ability to read external files as far as I know.
I'm faced with the exact same issue.
The way I solved it was by creating a function in Pine that pushes all my values into an [array](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Arrays.html), and then use that array to calculate and plot.
To move my data from Excel to Pine, I have a function that uses `concat()` to create a string for each value I have to add to the array.
Something like this:

```
myPineFunction(myArray, myExcelValue)
```

The drawback is that you have to edit your code, each time you have new values, but it's the best solution I've found so far.

Comment: That's neat! Unfortunately, the values update with change in price, so that's not practical for my usecase.